# Azure DevOps Environments; is there a limit to the number of VMs contained within a single Environment?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a limit to the number of VMs contained within a single Azure DevOps Environment? I google searched and searched the docs [including this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops) and have only found that there is no limit to the number tags one can put on an Environment, but can't find anything about the number of VMs an Environment can contain.

Has anyone found documentation of a fixed limit or run into a practical limit of any type?

Comment: I didn't find either. I just came across this GitHub issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5854.

Comment: I would expect that regular subscription limits would apply for those environments